# No Wipe Poo - Possible?

Tags: medical-science, hygiene, toilets

I read an article that says scientists have developed a pill that will make this possible, you take one pill with every meal and you'll no longer need to wipe after a bowel movement.

> This new technology released in pill form, is consumed with every meal
>   and will save time and money for everyone.

http://www.gomerblog.com/2013/09/no-wipe-poop/

I couldn't find any reference of these pills anywhere else, you'd think something this amazing would find it's way into other news sources. Is this a hoax?

Comment: Gomerblog.com is strictly a satirical and fake news blog site.

Comment: Ye who have never been fooled by a satire site, cast the first stone.  ;)  Sometimes it's just too bloody hard to tell when you first hear of something.  I give you a +1 for at least having the guts to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's a fake.**

[gomerblog.com's own disclaimer](http://www.gomerblog.com/disclaimer/) states:

> - **Gomerblog.com is strictly a satirical and fake news blog site.**  All articles are **fake** and not intended to diagnosis medical
>     conditions or to give medical advice.  Please see a real medical
>     website or your doctor for diagnosis and any medical advice. Please
>     don’t take any advice from our website.
> - [...]
> - All names and descriptions of people are fictitious except for those
>     of public figures, who are the subject of satire. Any resemblance to
>     actual persons or events is purely coincidental.